# Display a List of DataRows in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, datarow

I am trying to display a `List` of `DataRows` in a `DataGrid` like this:

```
List<DataRow> grid = new List<DataRow>();

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    grid.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
}
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = grid;
```

`dt` is a `DataTable` from where I get my data.
The problem is, when I run the code the `datagrid` is empty.

This didn't work, too:

```
datagrid1.DataContext = grid;
```

**Edit:**
(xaml)

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" />
```

Comment: Could you please share the xaml for `datagrid1`

Comment: Your code will work if you add `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in your xaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `List` of `DataRows`. You could simply:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Or:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

And:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

**Update**: If you still want a `List` of `DataRows`:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(grid.Contains)
                          .AsDataView();
```

Also you should change this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Comment: It would be great if you add, why `List<DataRow>` is not suitable for binding

Comment: @un-lucky It is unnecessary.

Comment: Later I want to manipulate some columns of selected rows, which is why I need that "i" from the for loop. Your simplified method works, but doesn't help me sorry

Comment: @reveN Also you should change `i <= dt.Rows.Count;` in you for loop to `i < dt.Rows.Count;`

Comment: After changing "<=" to this "<" it works. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use a foreach loop it is much more easier and you cant do mistakes.

```
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    grid.Add(row);
}
```